# Why this code for sorting in python falls into an infinite loop?

Tags: python, sorting, random

I want to take a list for sorting and sort it using python random library. The strategy to do this:

- First, take any two random index in the list we take as input
- Then swap those two elements.
- check if the list is sorted or not.
- if not sorted , repeat the steps again.

I am new in python. So not well acquainted with all the techniques . Please help with explanation. I cant figure out what is going wrong.

```
from random import randint

n=int(input())
l=[int(input()) for x in range(0,n)]

p=1

while (1):
  if(p==1):
    ransort(n)
  else:
    break

for x in l:
  print (x)


def ransort(n):
  i=randint(0,n-1)
  j=randint(0,n-1)
  l[i],l[j]=l[j],l[i]

  if l== l.sort():
    p=0
  else:
    p=1
  return p
```

Comment: This algorithm may just be _very_ inefficient.  Does it still run infinitely on small lists (of length 2 or 3?)

Comment: Because `p` has no opportunity to change value inside the `while` loop. The `p` inside the function is not the same as the global `p`

Comment: `l.sort()` sorts the list inplace and returns `None`.

Comment: Which, BTW, is only sane (`p`'s scope). You can look at `while (p==1): ransort(n)` and *see* whether and how `p` may or may not change. If `ransort` could/would change it from inside the function, that'd be spaghetti code.

Comment: This algorithm makes little to no sense.. `sort` already sorts the list in-place. Calling in in order to check if the list is already sorted is.. weird.

Comment: Well, now you've made it worse. `while (1)` will ***never end***. (Without a `break`, of which there's none.)

Comment: This is just an exercise program. So efficiency is not an issue but comprehension is. I still cant figure out what should be p's position. I have used built in sort method to check if the list is sorted or not.

Comment: If it  is required I can check the sorting without using sort() method. But I don't think the problem is due to that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. l.sort() makes an inplace sort so at the second iteration the list will be sorted
2. the "p" value in the script scope not changing, so the script goes in a loop

to avoid the infinite loop you can do 2 things:

check the returned value

```
while (p==1):
    p = ransort(n)
```

or in the ransort function edit the global variable value:

```
def ransort(n):
   i=randint(0,n-1)
   j=randint(0,n-1)
   l[i],l[j]=l[j],l[i]
   global p
   if l== l.sort():
       p=0
   else:
       p=1
```

**This works:**

```
def ransort(n):
  i=randint(0,n-1)
  j=randint(0,n-1)
  l[i],l[j]=l[j],l[i]
  global p
  if l== l.sort():
    p=0
  else:
    p=1
  return p #here it is

while p == 1:
  p =  ransort(n)
```

Comment: But it shows syntax error at global.                                                                                                   Error code is                                                                                                                               File "test.py", line 10\n
    global p=0\n
            ^\n
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you're right, look at the edit, the variable p is declared as global

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really worked.

Comment: But I had to declare p as global before function definition and also initialize it with 1. If I declare it only in function then it shows Nameerror at the line while (p==1). Please can you explain.                                                                                                                             My code is here:            https://repl.it/@sandipanman/SvelteInsidiousLogin

Comment: Sorry in the copy paste i miss a row, the ransort function has a "return p" , i'm going to edit the answer so you can understand